# Jquery function not working but don't got errors

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want my `<h2>` element to move to the center of the page, but that isn't what I'm stuck at, at the moment. I want it to move when I click on it and when I click it for the 2nd time I want it to go back.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sectiontitel').on('click', '.on', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).addClass('off');

        $(this).find('span').animate({
            'margin-left': '350px',
        },200);
    });

    $('.sectiontitel').on('click', '.off', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('off');
        $(this).addClass('on');

        $(this).find('span').animate({
            'margin-right': '350px',
        },200);
    });
});
```

This is the code I created so far and it doesn't give any errors, but it ain't working either.

Jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/uohu0r2o/1/

Comment: There are no elements in your fiddle that has the class `.on` or `.off`

Comment: No elements with .on or .off class to which you are binding click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wr19pjtb/)**

*Behaviour*: click on the `Lunch` header and you will see the movement.

2 key aspects:

- The `on` and `off` are added on the fly, hence i have registered it on `.sectiontitle`
- I have use `left: 0px`

<s>3rd you have spelling mistake in `title` beware it will slowly creep in your code base</s> #locales

Hope rest helps your need `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.sectiontitel', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).addClass('off');

        $(this).find('span').animate({
            'margin-left': '350px',
        },200);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.off', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('off');
        $(this).addClass('on');

        $(this).find('span').animate({
            'margin-left': '0px',
        },200);
    });
});
```

Comment: some locales spell it "titel" so this is not necessarily a typo

Comment: @Brandin saweeet, thanks and did you up voted me ? if yes your vote was a lucky 20 K mark and I will not forget you  `:)`